# How to center vertically and horizontally text in a div element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to center text above an image in an div element.

This is what i tried:

CSS:

```
    .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
}
.ring {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;

}
.flex_text  {
    position: absolute;
    color: #B64547;
    z-index: 100;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}


.cell img {
    display: block;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="cell">
            <h4 class="flex_text">Brewing, get started!</h4>
            <img src="img/Kaffe_1.jpg" alt="Ring1" class="ring">
        </div>
```

It did not work, obviously. The website is responsive, so the solution should work responsive aswell.

I looked around and tried a lot of different things but they didn't work.
I don't know, but maybe there's a solution with jquery?
Thanks :)

Comment: [Centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: That other question does not require a jquery solution.

Comment: // grab our divs
      var flex_text = $('.flex_text');
      var container = $('.container');

    // find half of the width difference between child and parent
      var left = (container.width() - flex_text.width()) / 2;

    // add the current left position of the parent and set the left css value
      left += container.offset().left;
      flex_text.css('left', left);

    // do the same for top position 
      var top = (container.height() - flex_text.height()) / 2;
      top += container.offset().top;
      flex_text.css('top', toppy);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: relative;` and `display: inline-block;` (or you can `float` it) on the parent element so it will draw a relatively positioned square around the image, then `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); left: 0; right: 0;` to center the text.

```css
    .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
}
.ring {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;

}
.cell {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.flex_text  {
    position: absolute;
    color: #B64547;
    z-index: 100;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


.cell img {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="cell">
            <h4 class="flex_text">Brewing, get started!</h4>
            <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" alt="Ring1" class="ring">
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working very well! I don't understand the transfrom:translateY(-50%) property yet but, I just got started with webdesign so I'll learn it ;)

Comment: @Janos awesome, you're welcome. that shifts an element up 50% of it's own height.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using flex here.

Check this snippet:

```css
.grid {
  position: relative;
}
.cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex_text {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
.cell img {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">
      <h4 class="flex_text">Brewing, get started!</h4>
      <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/9-credit-1.jpg" width=200px height=200px alt="Ring1" class="ring">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```